# Debian 10.9 fresh install will not boot

Tags: debian, dual-boot, grub

Just dumped Ubuntu in favor of Debian and not 5 hours in i am immediately regretting it and wanting all 5 back. Upon installing instead of being greeted by a GUI i am instead greeted by a console that will do nothing, the underscore just sits there and blinks. Any ideas? If not im going to have to reinstall Ubuntu and call it a day. (I also am booting alongside Windows 10 with grub).

edit: forgot to mention that its does with both computers i attempted to install it on.

Comment: Did you choose a desktop environment during installation? If not, this can be the intended behaviour. If you want a GUI you can later install a DE (GNOME/KDE/etc.). For now, are you able to login into the system and run some simple command (e.g. `echo hello `)?

Comment: Is it a BIOS or UEFI system? Is it only a flashing underscore or an actual prompt? At which point does it do this? I.E.: Does your bootloader choose the kernel, show a bunch of of boot messages, then just sit there? Or does it never even show your bootloader to choose a kernel to boot, etc? If it reaches the kernel and displays screens of boot messages, can you switch to another vterm (CTRL+ALT+F3, for example) to bring up a text-only login prompt?

Comment: It is a UEFI system, it kinda just shows a bunch of boot messages and sits there, i did choose a graphical interface but during installation even with an external device it said some ath10k firmware packages were missing

Comment: Also to be clear i got it working on one computer (installed firmware-linux) this didn't do anything to my laptop however

Answer (score 0):

ath10k is part of [firmware-atheros](https://packages.debian.org/buster/firmware-atheros), itself part of [firmware-nonfree](https://packages.debian.org/source/buster/firmware-nonfree).

Debian's [wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware) has a full paragraph about nonfree firmwares. It's a common problem as Debian avoid integration of nonfree softwares. Two solutions exist :

1. insert another USB dongle with [nonfree firmwares](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/firmware/) during install, while networking discovery is performed, or
2. use a special installation [CD including nonfree firmwares](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/) (never tried this solution, but seems simpler).

Comment: I already downloaded the atheros firmware package, i think its more of a gpu driver issue at this point because i am using a 3200u ryzen and vega 3 graphics. others seem to have issues and there isn't an easy solution it seems. my question is since the drivers from ubuntu worked can i hop over grab them from ubuntu and install them on buster?